# Template functions with HAML in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I'd like to be able to create template functions in Sinatra HAML templates that themselves contain haml. Is there any way to do this or something similar? It'd be cool if it could work with markdown too.

**foo.haml**

```
def foo(x)
   %h2 something
   %p something about #{x}

%h1 Herp de derp
= foo("mary")
= foo("us")
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do something like this:

```
# app.rb    

require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
helpers do
  def foo(name)
    haml = <<-HAML
#hello_block
   Hello, #{name}
HAML
    engine = Haml::Engine.new(haml)
    engine.render
  end
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

# index.haml
= foo 'World'
```

Comment: Yup, I found the helper functions too, but again, I want them to be _defined in_ the haml file. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Function is close, what you really need is what's known as a **partial**. These are predefined templates that you can place inside other views. For instance, you may have a *comment partial* to display a comment's author, timestamp, content, etc. You can then render this partial for each of the comments on a particular post.

Essentially, you'll end up with the following

```
# _foo.haml.erb
%h2 somthing
%p= x

# index.haml.erb
%h1 Herp de derp
= render :partial => "foo", :locals => { :x => "mary" }
= render :partial => "foo", :locals => { :x => "us" }
```

Comment: I'm aware of partials and am using them now to solve the problem, but I was really looking for something I can do within the file here to avoid having lots of files. One potential solution I found was content_for but I've been unable to get it working.